# what is the best way to count middle index for recursive or iterative call

Tags: java, algorithm

```
1) int mid = (right+left)/ 2;
2) int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
```

In practical Java execution second one is giving optimized function call(better time complexity).
It looks like both are giving same results for "mid" variable for a certain "left" and "right" value. Is there any prefernce or diffrence above two options.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read [this](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Comment: The first one will overflow if the sum of `right` and `left` is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Prefer using the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?  They are both fine for relatively small magnitude values of left and right.  But larger magnitude numbers suffer from integer overflow.

```
int right = Integer.MAX_VALUE-100;
int  left = Integer.MAX_VALUE-120;

int newLeft = left + (right-left)/2;
System.out.println(newLeft);
newLeft = (right + left)/2;  // = -222/2 = -111
System.out.println(newLeft); // oops!
```

Prints

```
2147483537
-111
```

And while we're on the topic, this is why it is bad practice to implement an `int` comparator like this:

```
Comparator<Integer> comp = (a, b) -> a - b;
```

When it should be like this

```
Comparator<Integer> comp  = (a, b) -> a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...thats clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is inaccurate and wrong. (2) is the fix and correct.

The question isn't about time complexity, it's about accuracy.

Assume that `right = 2,147,483,646` and `left = 2,147,483,646`. The addition of these will result in [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

The second one avoids the overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...that clarifies the difference.